# Ignore POST value from admin inline

Tags: django, django-admin

in django i have inlineadmin with some checkboxes, i want one of them to be ignored from saving if some condition applies.

I tried modifying request.POST['mykey'] or form.data['mykey'] in save_model() of main class with request.POST._mutable = True, but django save all anyway and for form.data it say is immutable.
I know i can set value for obj.mykey but how to save others and ignore one?

Many many thanks to all.

**UPDATE**

I build few lines of codes to explain better:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from testB.models import Book, Author

class BookInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    fields = ['author', 'title']


class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInLine]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            #do not save first title and do not change existing value

            # does not work
            # request.POST._mutable = True
            # request.POST['id_book_set-0-id']=''

            # does not owrk: querydict immutable
            # form.data['id_book_set-0-id']=''

            pass
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

Using has_change_permission is not the way, because user should be able to change other title lines, this is a backend check.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Use save_formset() instead of save_model():

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInLine]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for obj in formset.deleted_objects:
                obj.delete()
            for instance in instances:
                if request.user.is_superuser and instance.title != 'my title':
                    instance.save()
            formset.save_m2m()


admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```